# How to make multiple themed apps from one flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am looking to move from using Phonegap to using Flutter and currently, I have an app that can be themed multiple times from one project and deployed to IOS/Android stores

I know flutter has a theme class to be used across an app but I am looking to dynamically set this based on the app that is being used for example

```
Name: App A
Colors: red, blue, green

Name: App B
Colors: yellow, orange, purple
```

Both apps use the same code base and pages but are deployed as individual apps to the app stores

Is there an easy way to do this using flutter or would I need to create a new project for every new app that is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the multiple `flavors`

In android you can add a flavors in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
flavorDimensions "free"

productFlavors {

    free {
        dimension "app"
        applicationId "com.example.free"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    paid {
        dimension "app"
        applicationId "com.example.paid"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

and for `iOS` You can use the `iOS Schema`.

Below doc can help you in this:

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors

Comment: Thank you! So when it comes to building the apps is it possible to do something like $ flutter build ios --flavor all ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to use flavors, and for each flavor you should specify its own theme. Each flavor will have its own `main`. Using flavors with different application id allow you to upload distinct apps on the store with same code base.
Read more about flutter flavors [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors)